# Add callback instead of using default implementation

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, go, inheritance, callback

I'm using the following code which works as expected.

User add to the config `testers` (now its hard-coded but it will come from a config file) a new entry which is returning a list of `TAP` that he needs to check and run them in parallel via http call.

There is another use-case which I need to support that the user will be providing also a `function/method/callback` which the function will implement the call (instead the check() function) via http/curl/websocket/whatever he needs and
the function will **return response** whether it's 200/400/500.

For example let say that user implement two functions/callback in addition the list of config taps and the program will execute the functions the same as the list of `testers` and those functions will call to other sites like:  `"http://www.yahoo.com"` and `https://www.bing.com` with curl or http (just to demonstrate the difference) or even some is implemented the method check to return some child process execution result.

How can I do it in a clean way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type HT interface {
    Name() string
    Check() (*testerResponse, error)
}

type testerResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    res  http.Response
    url  string
}

type Tap struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func NewTap(name, url string, timeout time.Duration) *Tap {
    return &Tap{
        url:    url,
        name:   name,
        client: &http.Client{Timeout: timeout},
    }
}

func (p *Tap) Check() testerResponse {
    fmt.Printf("Fetching %s %s \n", p.name, p.url)
    // theres really no need for NewTap
    nt := NewTap(p.name, p.url, p.timeout)
    res, err := nt.client.Get(p.url)
    if err != nil {
        return testerResponse{err: err}
    }

    // need to close body
    res.Body.Close()
    return testerResponse{name: p.name, res: *res, url: p.url}
}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

// makeJobs fills up our jobs channel
func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Tap, taps []Tap) {
    for _, t := range taps {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

// getResults takes a job from our jobs channel, gets the result, and
// places it on the results channel
func getResults(tr <-chan testerResponse, taps []Tap) {
    for range taps {
        r := <-tr
        status := fmt.Sprintf("'%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", r.name, r.url, r.res.StatusCode)
        if r.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(r.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}

// worker defines our worker func. as long as there is a job in the
// "queue" we continue to pick up  the "next" job
func worker(jobs <-chan Tap, results chan<- testerResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        results <- n.Check()
    }
}

var (
    testers = []Tap{
        {
            name:    "1",
            url:     "http://google.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "3",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
    }
)

func main() {
    // Make buffered channels
    buffer := len(testers)
    jobsPipe := make(chan Tap, buffer)               // Jobs will be of type `Tap`
    resultsPipe := make(chan testerResponse, buffer) // Results will be of type `testerResponse`

    // Create worker pool
    // Max workers default is 5
    maxWorkers := 5
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    }

    makeJobs(jobsPipe, testers)
    getResults(resultsPipe, testers)
}
```

**update**
I've tried with the following
https://play.golang.org/p/cRPPzke27dZ

But not sure how to call to the `custom handlers` `check()` method to get also the data from them in parallel calls such as the `testers` configs

Comment: You're probably looking for a similar approach to what [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) is doing. If I'm wrong you could try to simplify your question so that someone might actually understand.

Comment: Question not very clear

Comment: @mkopriva - I tried to make it more simple :) (I hope)  let say the the program is getting the configuration file with the list of the `testers` , this is how it work now (except the config is hard-coded but it should be a problem...) now let say that I want to support another scenario when this application is getting also a function which user implement the `check` inside and the program needs only to execute this function and get the status, how should I support this approach? please let me know if it more clear now ?if not please let me know what and i'll do my best to improve it...

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava - let say the the program is getting the configuration file with the list of the testers , this is how it work now (except the config is hard-coded but it should be a problem...) now let say that I want to support another scenario when this application is getting also a function which user implement the check inside and the program needs only to execute this function and get the status, how should I support this approach? please let me know if it more clear now ? if not please let me know what and i'll do my best to improve it...

Comment: @RaynD Do you want to create a worker queue with a list of jobs that define their own job function?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava - yes, now all the testers run the `check()` method, the new use-case is to provide additional functions that run there own check are return the response with success or failure...

Comment: @RaynD https://play.golang.org/p/A-Cl2ckBmA0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 5 (accepted answer)

---

**Since you are interested in this question, you may also be interested in this one as well. [See here for more on how to run each job with an auto-cancelling timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210104/use-job-with-time-and-timeout/64210733#64210733).**

---

To answer your question how would you add random functions..

I have no idea what type you are wanting to return, but you can do anything you wanted.

There are about a million different ways you could do this, this is just one example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
)

var (
    numWorkers = 10
)

type MyReturnType struct {
    Name string
    Data interface{}
}

func wrapJob(rc chan MyReturnType, f func() MyReturnType) func() {
    return func() {
        rc <- f()
    }
}

func main() {
    // create results chan and worker pool
    // should prob make your results channel typed to what you need
    jobs := []func() MyReturnType {
        func() MyReturnType {
            // whatever you want to do here
            return MyReturnType{Name: "job1", Data: map[string]string{"Whatever": "You want"}}
        },
        func() MyReturnType {
            // whatever you want to do here
            // do a curl or a kubectl or whatever you want
            resultFromCurl := "i am a result"
            return MyReturnType{Name: "job2", Data: resultFromCurl}
        },
    }

    results := make(chan MyReturnType, len(jobs))
    pool := workerpool.New(numWorkers)

    for _, job := range jobs {
        j := job
        pool.Submit(wrapJob(results, j))
    }

    // Wait for all jobs to finish
    pool.StopWait()

    // Close results chan
    close(results)

    // Iterate over results, printing to console
    for res := range results {
        prettyPrint(res)
    }
}

func prettyPrint(i interface{}) {
    prettyJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s \n", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("MyReturnType %s\n", string(prettyJSON))
}
```

Which returns:

```golang
// MyReturnType {
//     "Name": "job2",
//     "Data": "i am a result"
// }
// MyReturnType {
//     "Name": "job1",
//     "Data": {
//         "Whatever": "You want"
//     }
// }
```

### Update 4

After digging into this for a number of hours, I would recommend using something like `workerpool`, which [you can find here](https://github.com/gammazero/workerpool). Honestly, using `workerpool` seems to make the most sense here.. It looks production ready and is used by a handful of rather big names (see the readme in their repo).

I wrote a little example that shows how you can use `workerpool`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
)

var (
    numWorkers = 10
    urls       = []string{"yahoo.com", "example.com", "google.com"}
)

func main() {
    // create results chan and worker pool
    // should prob make your results channel typed to what you need
    results := make(chan interface{}, len(urls))
    pool := workerpool.New(numWorkers)

    // Create jobs by iterating over urls
    for i, u := range urls {
        url := u
        jobNum := i

        // Create job
        f := func() {
            start := time.Now()
            c := &http.Client{}
            r, e := c.Get("http://" + url)
            if e != nil {
                fmt.Println(e.Error())
            }
            took := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
            o := fmt.Sprintf("completed job '%d' to '%s' in '%dms' with status code '%d'\n", jobNum, url, took, r.StatusCode)
            results <- o
        }

        // Add job to workerpool
        pool.Submit(f)
    }

    // Wait for all jobs to finish
    pool.StopWait()

    // Close results chan
    close(results)

    // Iterate over results, printing to console
    for res := range results {
        fmt.Printf(res.(string))
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```golang
// completed job '1' to 'example.com' in '81ms' with status code '200'
// completed job '2' to 'google.com' in '249ms' with status code '200'
// completed job '0' to 'yahoo.com' in '816ms' with status code '200'
```

### Update 3

I went ahead and wrote a worker pool library (with the help of [`workerpool`](https://github.com/gammazero/workerpool)) as I also wanted to dive deeper into channels and concurrency design.

[You can find the repo here](https://github.com/oze4/puddle) and the code below.

How to use:

```golang
pool := New(3)

pool.Job(func() {
    c := &http.Client{}
    r, e := c.Get("http://google.com")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("To google.com %d\n", r.StatusCode)
})

pool.Job(func() {
    c := &http.Client{}
    r, e := c.Get("http://yahoo.com")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("To yahoo.com %d\n", r.StatusCode)
})

pool.Job(func() {
    c := &http.Client{}
    r, e := c.Get("http://example.com")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("To example.com %d\n", r.StatusCode)
})

pool.Seal()
```

#### Code for worker pool (puddle)

```golang
package puddle

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    idleTimeout = time.Second * 2
)

// New creates a new puddle (aka worker pool)
func New(maxWorkers int) Puddle {
    // There must be at least one worker
    if maxWorkers < 1 {
        maxWorkers = 1
    }

    p := &puddle{
        maxWorkers: maxWorkers,
        jobs:       make(chan func(), 1),
        workers:    make(chan func()),
        killswitch: make(chan struct{}),
    }

    // Start accepting/working jobs as they come in
    go p.serve()

    return p
}

// Puddle knows how to interact with worker pools
type Puddle interface {
    Job(f func())
    Seal()
}

// puddle is a worker pool that holds workers, tasks, and misc metadata
type puddle struct {
    maxWorkers int
    jobs       chan func()
    workers    chan func()
    killswitch chan struct{}
    queue      List
    once       sync.Once
    stopped    int32
    waiting    int32
    wait       bool
}

// Job submits a new task to the worker pool
func (p *puddle) Job(f func()) {
    if f != nil {
        p.jobs <- f
    }
}

// Seal stops worker pool and waits for queued tasks to complete
func (p *puddle) Seal() {
    p.stop(true)
}

func (p *puddle) stop(wait bool) {
    p.once.Do(func() {
        p.wait = wait
        // Close task queue and wait for currently running tasks to finish
        close(p.jobs)
    })
    <-p.killswitch
}

func (p *puddle) killWorkerIfIdle() bool {
    select {
    case p.workers <- nil:
        // Kill worker
        return true
    default:
        // No ready workers
        return false
    }
}

// process puts new jobs onto the queue, and removes jobs from the queue as workers become available.
// Returns false if puddle is stopped.
func (p *puddle) process() bool {
    select {
    case task, ok := <-p.jobs:
        if !ok {
            return false
        }
        p.queue.PushBack(task)
    case p.workers <- p.queue.Front().Value.(func()):
        // Give task to ready worker
        p.queue.PopFront()
    }
    return true
}

func (p *puddle) serve() {
    defer close(p.killswitch)
    timeout := time.NewTimer(idleTimeout)
    var workerCount int
    var idle bool

Serving:
    for {
        if p.queue.Len() != 0 {
            if !p.process() {
                break Serving
            }
            continue
        }

        select {
        case job, ok := <-p.jobs:
            if !ok {
                break Serving
            }

            // Give a task to our workers
            select {
            case p.workers <- job:
            default:
                // If we are not maxed on workers, create a new one
                if workerCount < p.maxWorkers {
                    go startJob(job, p.workers)
                    workerCount++
                } else {
                    // Place a task on the back of the queue
                    p.queue.PushBack(job)
                }
            }
            idle = false
        case <-timeout.C:
            // Timed out waiting for work to arrive.  Kill a ready worker if
            // pool has been idle for a whole timeout.
            if idle && workerCount > 0 {
                if p.killWorkerIfIdle() {
                    workerCount--
                }
            }
            idle = true
            timeout.Reset(idleTimeout)
        }
    }

    // Allow queued jobs to complete
    if p.wait {
        p.work()
    }

    // Stop all workers before shutting down
    for workerCount > 0 {
        p.workers <- nil
        workerCount--
    }

    timeout.Stop()
}

// work removes each task from the waiting queue and gives it to
// workers until queue is empty.
func (p *puddle) work() {
    for p.queue.Len() != 0 {
        // A worker is ready, so give task to worker.
        p.workers <- p.queue.PopFront()
    }
}

// startJob runs initial task, then starts a worker waiting for more.
func startJob(job func(), workerQueue chan func()) {
    job()
    go worker(workerQueue)
}

// worker executes tasks and stops when it receives a nil task.
func worker(queue chan func()) {
    for job := range queue {
        if job == nil {
            return
        }
        job()
    }
}

// List wraps `container/list`
type List struct {
    list.List
}

// PopFront removes then returns first element in list as func()
func (l *List) PopFront() func() {
    f := l.Front()
    l.Remove(f)
    return f.Value.(func())
}
```

### Update 2

Since you were asking about how to use the code, this is how you would do so.

I turned `worker` into it's own package, as well as wrote another repo to show how to use that package.

- [worker package](https://github.com/oze4/worker)
- [how to use worker package](https://github.com/oze4/worker-in-action)

#### `worker` package

```golang
package worker

import "fmt"

type JobResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    res  int
    url  string
}

type Job interface {
    Name() string
    Callback() JobResponse
}

func Do(jobs []Job, maxWorkers int) {
    jobsPool := make(chan Job, len(jobs))
    resultsPool := make(chan JobResponse, len(jobs))

    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(jobsPool, resultsPool)
    }

    makeJobs(jobsPool, jobs)
    getResults(resultsPool, jobs)
}

func worker(jobs <-chan Job, response chan<- JobResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        response <- n.Callback()
    }
}

func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Job, queue []Job) {
    for _, t := range queue {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

func getResults(response <-chan JobResponse, queue []Job) {
    for range queue {
        job := <-response
        status := fmt.Sprintf("[result] '%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", job.name, job.url, job.res)
        if job.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(job.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}
```

#### How to use worker package

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/oze4/worker"
)

func main() {
    jobs := []worker.Job{
        AddedByUser{name: "1"},
        AddedByUser{name: "2"},
        AddedByUser{name: "3"},
        AddedByUser{name: "4"},
        AddedByUser{name: "5"},
        AddedByUser{name: "6"},
    }
    
    worker.Do(jobs, 5)
}

type AddedByUser struct {
    name string
}

func (a AddedByUser) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a AddedByUser) Callback() worker.JobResponse {
    // User added func/callback goes here
    return worker.JobResponse{}
}
```

### Update

I renamed some things to hopefully help make it a little more clear.

This is the basics of what you need:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

type JobResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    res  int
    url  string
}

type Job interface {
    Name() string
    Callback() JobResponse
}

func worker(jobs <-chan Job, response chan<- JobResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        response <- n.Callback()
    }
}

func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Job, queue []Job) {
    for _, t := range queue {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

func getResults(response <-chan JobResponse, queue []Job) {
    for range queue {
        j := <-response
        status := fmt.Sprintf("[result] '%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", j.name, j.url, j.res)
        if j.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(j.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}
```

As long as I satisfy the `Job` interface I can pass it into worker, makeJobs, and getResults:

```golang
type AddedByUser struct {
    name string
}

func (a AddedByUser) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a AddedByUser) Callback() JobResponse {
    // User added func/callback goes here
    return JobResponse{}
}
```

Like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jobsPool := make(chan Job, len(testers))
    resultsPool := make(chan JobResponse, len(testers))

    maxWorkers := 5
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(jobsPool, resultsPool)
    }

    makeJobs(jobsPool, testers)
    getResults(resultsPool, testers)
}

var testers = []Job{
    AddedByUser{name: "abu"}, // Using different types in Job
    Tap{name: "tap"},         // Using different types in Job
}

type AddedByUser struct {
    name string
}

func (a AddedByUser) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a AddedByUser) Callback() JobResponse {
    // User added func/callback goes here
    return JobResponse{}
}

type Tap struct {
    name string
}

func (t Tap) Name() string {
    return t.name
}

func (t Tap) Callback() JobResponse {
    // User added func/callback goes here
    return JobResponse{}
}

type JobResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    res  int
    url  string
}

type Job interface {
    Name() string
    Callback() JobResponse
}

func worker(jobs <-chan Job, response chan<- JobResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        response <- n.Callback()
    }
}

func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Job, queue []Job) {
    for _, t := range queue {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

func getResults(response <-chan JobResponse, queue []Job) {
    for range queue {
        job := <-response
        status := fmt.Sprintf("[result] '%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", job.name, job.url, job.res)
        if job.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(job.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

[adding this answer because OP and I have been talking outside of this thread]

You had a couple errors in your code, but at the end of the day all you had to do was take the advice people were giving you. You just had to connect the dots. I suggest troubleshooting your code and trying to fully understand what the issue is. That is honestly the only way to learn.

The biggest issues I can remember were:

- Needed to modify your `HT` interface so the `Check(...)` signature matched each method

  - Otherwise, those structs (`Tap`, `Tap1`, `Tap2`) do not satisfy the `HT` interface and therefore do not implement HT
- The param type(s) in funcs `worker(...)`, `makeJobs(...)`, and `getResults(...)` were changed from `[]Tap` to `[]HT`
- You were not aggregating all Taps into one slice

  - The only reason we can use all different Taps as HT is because they all implement HT

Is something like this what you're looking for?

https://play.golang.org/p/zLmKOKAnX4C

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    // "os/exec"
    "time"
)

type HT interface {
    Name() string
    Check() testerResponse
}

type testerResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    //res  http.Response
    res int
    url string
}

type Tap struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func (p *Tap) Check() testerResponse {
    fmt.Printf("[job][Tap1] Fetching %s %s \n", p.name, p.url)
    p.client = &http.Client{Timeout: p.timeout}
    res, err := p.client.Get(p.url)
    if err != nil {
        return testerResponse{err: err}
    }

    // need to close body
    res.Body.Close()
    return testerResponse{name: p.name, res: res.StatusCode, url: p.url}
}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

// ---- CUSTOM CHECKS-------------
// ---- 1. NEW specific function -------------

type Tap2 struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func (p *Tap2) Check() testerResponse {
    // Do some request here.....
    fmt.Printf("[job][Tap2] Fetching %s %s \n", p.name, p.url)
    return testerResponse{res: 200, url: p.url, name: p.name}
}

func (p *Tap2) Name() string {
    return "yahoo custom check"
}

// ---- 2. NEW specific function which is not running http

type Tap3 struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func (p *Tap3) Check() testerResponse {
    // Do some request here....
    fmt.Printf("[job][Tap3] Fetching %s %s \n", p.name, p.url)
    return testerResponse{res: 200, url: p.url, name: p.name}
}

func (p *Tap3) Name() string {
    return "custom check2"
}

// makeJobs fills up our jobs channel
func makeJobs(jch chan<- HT, jobs []HT) {
    for _, t := range jobs {
        jch <- t
    }
}

// getResults takes a job from our jobs channel, gets the result, and
// places it on the results channel
func getResults(tr <-chan testerResponse, jobs []HT) []testerResponse {
    var rts []testerResponse
    var r testerResponse
    for range jobs {
        r = <-tr
        status := fmt.Sprintf("[result] '%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", r.name, r.url, r.res)
        if r.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(r.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
        rts = append(rts, r)
    }
    return rts
}

// worker defines our worker func. as long as there is a job in the
// "queue" we continue to pick up  the "next" job
func worker(jobs <-chan HT, results chan<- testerResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        results <- n.Check()
    }
}

var (
    testers1 = []Tap{
        {
            name:    "First Tap1",
            url:     "http://google.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "Second Tap1",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
    }

    testers2 = []Tap2{
        {
            name: "First Tap2",
            url:  "http://1.tap2.com",
        },
        {
            name: "Second Tap2",
            url:  "http://2.tap2.com",
        },
    }

    testers3 = []Tap3{
        {
            name: "First Tap3",
            url:  "http://1.tap3.com",
        },
        {
            name: "Second Tap3",
            url:  "http://2.tap3.com",
        },
    }
)

func main() {
    // Aggregate all testers into one slice
    var testers []HT
    for _, t1 := range testers1 {
        testers = append(testers, &t1)
    }
    for _, t2 := range testers2 {
        testers = append(testers, &t2)
    }
    for _, t3 := range testers3 {
        testers = append(testers, &t3)
    }

    // Make buffered channels
    buffer := len(testers)
    jobsPipe := make(chan HT, buffer)                // Jobs will be of type `HT`
    resultsPipe := make(chan testerResponse, buffer) // Results will be of type `testerResponse`

    // Create worker pool
    // Max workers default is 5
    maxWorkers := 5
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    }

    makeJobs(jobsPipe, testers)
    getResults(resultsPipe, testers)
    //fmt.Println("at the end",tr)
}
```

Which outputs:

```golang
// [job][Tap1] Fetching Second Tap1 http://stackoverflow.com 
// [job][Tap2] Fetching Second Tap2 http://2.tap2.com 
// [job][Tap3] Fetching Second Tap3 http://2.tap3.com 
// [job][Tap3] Fetching Second Tap3 http://2.tap3.com 
// [result] 'Second Tap2' to 'http://2.tap2.com' was fetched with status '200'
// [result] 'Second Tap3' to 'http://2.tap3.com' was fetched with status '200'
// [result] 'Second Tap3' to 'http://2.tap3.com' was fetched with status '200'
// [job][Tap2] Fetching Second Tap2 http://2.tap2.com 
// [job][Tap1] Fetching Second Tap1 http://stackoverflow.com 
// [result] 'Second Tap2' to 'http://2.tap2.com' was fetched with status '200'
// [result] 'Second Tap1' to 'http://stackoverflow.com' was fetched with status '200'
// [result] 'Second Tap1' to 'http://stackoverflow.com' was fetched with status '200'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222471/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-oestreich-add-callback-instead-of-using-default-imp).

Comment: Thank you for your time!, I understand the direction it make sense. what about custom function which `not` running http request, how would you `add` it to the current implementation ?

Comment: my question is how would you add additional function `http` to the current (what you provide already in the example) pool?

Comment: What do you mean @RaynD you just add it to the worker pool...?

Comment: lets say you have another function which you need to run which is not running the `http` call, should run some `curl`  or `kubectl` for example, how would you do it?

Comment: I think we are starting to go out of the scope of this question, but please see my latest update. You can literally do *anything* you wanted here.

Comment: Ok, great thank you very much, this is what i need. i'll test it to my use-case now, one question, can we define `timeout` for each job ?

Comment: You control each job you can set any timeout you want. Again, ***you can literally do anything you want***.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please make sure to mark it as accepted and assign the bounty. I'd be more than happy to help with the timeout issue if you want to create a separate question for that since it is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I've done it as you did great works. in case of question will open new one. thanks you sir!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222535/discussion-between-rayn-d-and-matt-oestreich).

Comment: as discussed, I've opened a new question please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210104/go-use-job-with-time-and-timeout

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want your worker to accept other testers

After looking at your code seems you have all the pieces in the right place and would need some minor changes here

```
// makeJobs fills up our jobs channel
func makeJobs(jobs chan<- HT, taps []Tap) {
    for _, t := range taps {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

// getResults takes a job from our jobs channel, gets the result, and
// places it on the results channel
func getResults(tr <-chan HT, taps []Tap) {
    for range taps {
        r := <-tr
        status := fmt.Sprintf("'%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", r.name, r.url, r.res.StatusCode)
        if r.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(r.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}

// worker defines our worker func. as long as there is a job in the
// "queue" we continue to pick up  the "next" job
func worker(jobs <-chan HT, results chan<- testerResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        results <- n.Check()
    }
}
```

Now if you see your job queue can accept any type that implements HT interface so if you want a new Job say Tap2 you just

```
type Tap2 struct{...}

func (p *Tap2) Check() testerResponse {...}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {...}
```

Now you can push Tap and Tap2 to same jobQueue as job Queue accepts any type that implements HT

Comment: see here not sure if I did it right,if so, not sure how to call to custom functions to get the data https://play.golang.org/p/cRPPzke27dZ