# Use job with time and timeout

Tags: go

I use the following sample code which works, now I want that each job be able
to print the time it took to execute (it's better as generic that not each job will need to use the code of

```go
start := time.Now()
took := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
```

And also provide a timeout for a job, for example, if it takes more then 10 seconds to kill it or stop it.

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
)

var numWorkers = 10

type MyReturnType struct {
    Name string
    Data interface{}
}

func wrapJob(rc chan MyReturnType, f func() MyReturnType) func() {
    return func() {
        rc <- f()
    }
}

func main() {
    // create results chan and worker pool
    // should prob make your results channel typed to what you need
    jobs := []func() MyReturnType {
        func() MyReturnType {
           return job1()
        },
        func() MyReturnType {
           return job2()
        },
    }

    results := make(chan MyReturnType, len(jobs))
    pool := workerpool.New(numWorkers)

    for _, job := range jobs {
        j := job
        pool.Submit(wrapJob(results, j))
    }

    // Wait for all jobs to finish
    pool.StopWait()

    // Close results chan
    close(results)

    // Iterate over results, printing to console
    for res := range results {
        prettyPrint(res)
    }
}

func prettyPrint(i interface{}) {
    prettyJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s \n", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("MyReturnType %s\n", string(prettyJSON))
}
```

Here is an example of what I try to avoid and to provide some general solution for printing time for each job:

```go
func job1() {
   start := time.Now()
   ...
   // running some code
   took := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
}

func job2(){
   start := time.Now()
   ...
   // running some code
   took := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
}
```

Comment: What's your question? For timeouts and cancellation use [contexts](https://golang.org/pkg/context/).

Comment: @Peter - OK i'll check it out, but for printing the time that it tooks see my update

Comment: Print in the anonymous function returned by wrapJob.

Comment: @Peter - do you mean something like ` return func() {
  start := time.Now()
  rc <- f()
  took := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
  fmt.Println(time.Duration(took))
 }` ?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you want to include the potential time to wait for a receiver.

Comment: @Peter - The time to wait for receiver(function) should be nano seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

***Scroll to section "This is the accepted answer" to view the accepted answer***

I went ahead and wrote a little library from the code in the accepted answer...

[You can find it here](https://github.com/oze4/reactor-go) or the code below:

```golang
// How to use the library
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/oze4/reactor"
)

func main() {
    timeoutForJobs := time.Duration(time.Second * 10)
    numOfWorkers := 10

    myreactor := reactor.New(numOfWorkers, timeoutForJobs)

    // You can also create a Reactor with a custom Client
    // myreactor := reactor.NewWithClient(numOfWorkers, timeoutForJobs, &reactor.Client{...})

    // Add job(s)
    myreactor.Add(reactor.Job{
        Name: "job1",
        Runner: func(c *reactor.Client) reactor.React {
            // do something with client `c`
            res, _ := c.HTTP.Get("xyz.com")
            return reactor.React{Info: res}
        },
    })

    // All results will be here
    results := myreactor.GetResults()
    
    for _, result := range results {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

#### Code for library

```golang
// Library code
package reactor

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
)

// New creates a new Reactor
func New(maxWorkers int, jobTimeout time.Duration) Reactor {
    // Do whatever you need to here to create default client
    defaultClient := &Client{
        HTTP:       http.Client{},
        Kubernetes: kubernetes.Clientset{},
    }

    return &reactor{
        workerPool:  workerpool.New(maxWorkers),
        jobTimeout:  jobTimeout,
        transport:   defaultClient,
        resultsChan: make(chan React, 100),
    }
}

// NewWithClient creates a new Reactor with a custom client
func NewWithClient(client *Client, maxWorkers int, jobTimeout time.Duration) Reactor {
    return &reactor{
        workerPool:  workerpool.New(maxWorkers),
        jobTimeout:  jobTimeout,
        transport:   client,
        resultsChan: make(chan React, 100),
    }
}

// Reactor knows how to handle jobs
type Reactor interface {
    Add(j Job)                          // Add puts a job on the queue
    Client() *Client                    // I dont know if you want the consumer to have access to this or not
    GetResults() []React                // Get results
    Timeout() time.Duration             // I dont know if you want the consumer to have access to this or not
    WorkerPool() *workerpool.WorkerPool // I dont know if you want the consumer to have access to this or not
}

type reactor struct {
    jobTimeout  time.Duration
    workerPool  *workerpool.WorkerPool
    resultsChan chan React
    transport   *Client
}

// Add submits a job
func (r *reactor) Add(j Job) {
    r.workerPool.Submit(r.wrapper(j))
}

// I dont know if you want the consumer to have access to this or not
func (r *reactor) Client() *Client {
    return r.transport
}

// Get results gets results
func (r *reactor) GetResults() []React {
    return r.getResults()
}

func (r *reactor) getResults() []React {
    r.workerPool.StopWait()
    close(r.resultsChan)

    var allReacts []React
    for jobreact := range r.resultsChan {
        allReacts = append(allReacts, jobreact)
    }

    return allReacts
}

func (r *reactor) Timeout() time.Duration {
    return r.jobTimeout
}

// I dont know if you want the consumer to have access to this or not
func (r *reactor) WorkerPool() *workerpool.WorkerPool {
    return r.workerPool
}

// worker should be private
func (r *reactor) worker(ctx context.Context, done context.CancelFunc, job Job, start time.Time) {
    runner := job.Runner(r.transport)
    runner.duration = time.Since(start)
    runner.name = job.Name

    if ctx.Err() == nil {
        r.resultsChan <- runner
    }

    done()
}

// wrapper should be private
func (r *reactor) wrapper(job Job) func() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), r.jobTimeout)

    return func() {
        start := time.Now()
        go r.worker(ctx, cancel, job, start)

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            switch ctx.Err() {
            case context.DeadlineExceeded:
                r.resultsChan <- React{
                    Error:    context.DeadlineExceeded,
                    name:     job.Name,
                    duration: time.Since(start),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// React holds response data
type React struct {
    // This should be public so the consumer can set it
    Info  interface{}
    Error error

    // These fields should be private and handled via public methods
    duration time.Duration
    name     string
}

// Duration returns duration
func (r *React) Duration() time.Duration {
    return r.duration
}

// Name returns the job name
func (r *React) Name() string {
    return r.name
}

// Client holds http and kubernetes clients
type Client struct {
    HTTP       http.Client
    Kubernetes kubernetes.Clientset
}

// Job holds job data
type Job struct {
    Name   string
    Runner func(*Client) React
}
```

---

## This is the accepted answer

The following example shows how you can gather execution time as well as set a timeout..

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
)

var (
    //
    // Set timeout for all jobs here
    //
    jobTimeout = time.Duration(time.Second * 1)
)

// MyReturnType could be anything you want it to be
type MyReturnType struct {
    name              string
    Data              interface{}
    Error             error
    ExecutionDuration time.Duration
}

// Name returns name. It is written like this so the consumer
// cannot change the name outside of supplying one via the Job
func (m *MyReturnType) Name() string {
    return m.name
}

// Job holds job data
type Job struct {
    Name string
    Task func() MyReturnType
}

func wrapJob(timeout time.Duration, resultsChan chan MyReturnType, job Job) func() {
    timeoutContext, timeoutCancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)

    return func() {
        timerStart := time.Now()
        go func(ctx context.Context, done context.CancelFunc, resChan chan MyReturnType, todo Job, startTime time.Time) {
            result := todo.Task()
            result.ExecutionDuration = time.Since(startTime)
            result.name = todo.Name
            if timeoutContext.Err() == nil {
                resChan <- result
            }
            done()
        }(timeoutContext, timeoutCancel, resultsChan, job, timerStart)

        select {
        case <-timeoutContext.Done():
            switch timeoutContext.Err() {
            case context.DeadlineExceeded:
                resultsChan <- MyReturnType{
                    name:              job.Name,
                    Error:             context.DeadlineExceeded,
                    ExecutionDuration: time.Since(timerStart),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    jobs := []Job{
        {
            Name: "job1",
            Task: func() MyReturnType {
                // This will surpass our timeout and should get cancelled
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
                // Don't have to set the name here
                return MyReturnType{Data: map[string]string{"Whatever": "You want"}}
            },
        },
        {
            Name: "job2",
            Task: func() MyReturnType {
                // This job will succeed
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
                resultFromCurl := "i am a result"
                return MyReturnType{Data: resultFromCurl}
            },
        },
    }

    jobResultsChannel := make(chan MyReturnType, len(jobs))
    pool := workerpool.New(10)

    for _, job := range jobs {
        pool.Submit(wrapJob(jobTimeout, jobResultsChannel, job))
    }

    pool.StopWait()
    close(jobResultsChannel)

    // Do whatever you want with results
    for jobResult := range jobResultsChannel {
        if jobResult.Error != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[took '%d' ms] '%s' : JobError : %s\n", jobResult.ExecutionDuration, jobResult.Name(), jobResult.Error)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("[took '%d' ms] '%s' : JobSuccess : %s\n", jobResult.ExecutionDuration, jobResult.Name(), jobResult.Data)
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```golang
// [took '305182398' ms] 'job2' : JobSuccess : i am a result
// [took '1001045539' ms] 'job1' : JobError : context deadline exceeded
```

---

### Original Answer

You should be able to use context for timeouts/cancellation ([as Peter mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210104/go-use-job-with-time-and-timeout/64210733#comment113543611_64210104)).

As far as recording execution time, you could do [what you stated in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210104/go-use-job-with-time-and-timeout/64210733#comment113543952_64210104), or something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
)

type MyReturnType struct {
    Name string
    Data interface{}
    Time time.Duration
}

func wrapJob(rc chan MyReturnType, f func() MyReturnType) func() {
    return func() {
        start := time.Now()
        result := f()
        result.Time = time.Since(start)
        rc <- result
    }
}

func main() {
    jobs := []func() MyReturnType{
        func() MyReturnType {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*400)
            return MyReturnType{Name: "job1", Data: map[string]string{"Whatever": "You want"}}
        },
        func() MyReturnType {
            resultFromCurl := "i am a result"
            return MyReturnType{Name: "job2", Data: resultFromCurl}
        },
    }

    results := make(chan MyReturnType, len(jobs))
    pool := workerpool.New(10)

    for _, job := range jobs {
        j := job
        pool.Submit(wrapJob(results, j))
    }

    pool.StopWait()
    close(results)

    for res := range results {
        fmt.Printf("[took '%d' ms] ", res.Time)
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 1+! if it's not too complicated it would be great if you can add an example for the cancellation.

Comment: Thanks, what should be in the switch fork `   case context.Canceled:
    // success
   }`> ?  not sure I understand it...

Comment: Nothing you can actually remove that case.

Comment: ok thank you. im checking it.so it should be just `if` , correct? or switch should be used?

Comment: switch needs to be used. see my update. i tried to clean it up some.

Comment: thanks, ok looks ok, the only thing that is missing the job name, it doesnt print the job name if you return some `Name` `foo`  /  `"job2"`inside the job definition ..

Comment: Well, yeah. Did you read the code? The fix is rather simple.

Comment: I have no idea how you want to name things, or if you even want to use `MyReturnType` - I am literally trying to abstract everything you are explaining. I can only give you so much.  I have provided you a ton of solid code that you can study and learn from.

Comment: No, I think you didnt understand :) , I mean the `job2` value which is defined in the jobs , this `fmt.Printf("[took '%d' ms] '%s' : JobError : %s\n", jobResult.ExecutionDuration, jobResult.Name, jobResult.Error)` doesn't print it...any idea why?

Comment: Yes I understand completely. The fix is easy. It's because I am setting default job names. Play around with the code. Move some things around to fit what you need. I can only give you so much before you have to take over. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You're not disturbing. No worries. Just try some stuff before asking - then if you can't figure it out that's when you ask. But your questions are very basic at this point and it's like you're not even reading the code or playing with it. I'm here to help you, not to write code for you. No hard feelings :)

Comment: ok, yes I know but what confuses me is this `jobName := fmt.Sprintf("Job # %d", i)` which is should be there as it should come from the returns of the job response.

Comment: Correct. So remove it and see what happens. I had to step away from my computer but I think the last part I had trouble with was getting the job name in the error message. Otherwise we don't know which job failed, just that a job failed. Give me like 30 minutes and I'll fix it up. I have an idea.

Comment: @RaynD please see my latest update.. that should do the trick.

Comment: This is my last question on this topic :) I've tried something which Im not sure about, it will be great if you can have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232012/go-pass-different-clients-to-generic-function , hopefully there will be a minor change. thank you!

Comment: @RaynD see the latest update here.. You should consider turning all of the code we have been working on into it's own package (like my update shows).